# PostGIS is_simple doesn't work for 3D linestring

Tags: postgis, data-validation

I would like to check linestring-z validity with PostGIS. Specifically, to check whether the features are "Simple" (not self-intersect). My linestring contains X,Y,Z
which looks like the below (labeling z value):
[image]

From the reference provided by PostGIS - https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsSimple.html, they mentioned 3D is supported and Z index is considered. But when I run the query below, the result returned false (not valid).

```
sql = SELECT ST_IsSimple('LINESTRING Z (1 1 18, 5 5 17, 1 7 0, 3 0 0)'::geometry) as simple;
```

The function acted as if the data is 2D and omitting the Z value. My question is does ST_IsSimple works with 3D as indicated by the reference. If yes, what did I do wrong? If no, is there any alternative that I could do to check the validity of a linestring z?

Comment: This is interesting. The wording is similar in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersects.html so it feels like IsSimple is really meant to support 3D geometries, not only to accept them as a "2D with height attribute".

Comment: It is stated that it implements OGC simple feature specifications... and there isn't specified how to handle Z coordinates. My understanding is that ST_IsSimle performs tests only in 2D. Same as ST_IsValid.

Comment: `ST_IsSimple` in PostGIS works only with the 2D coordinates.